# Copying to network share does not work with powershell Copy-Item

Tags: windows, powershell, samba

I try to copy with powershell in Windows 10 a install folder to a network share (samba on linux)

```bsh
powershell.exe -Version 5 -Command "Copy-Item  -Force -Path 'install' -Recurse -Destination 
'\\\\intranet.server.com\install'" -Container
```

It always fails, even if files can be written in the explorere and I have access, with a lot of these messages:

```
Copy-Item : The target file "\\intranet.server.com\install\a\b\c" is a directory, not a file.
```

Deleteing any existing folder works well with `Remove-Item '\\intranet.server.com\install\*' -Force -Recurse`

I dont know if it has to do with credentials, how can I debug this?

Comment: Do you get that for all files and folders? Or does `Copy-Item` work on some? If so, what's the difference between working and not working files/folders? Are there symbolic links involved?

Comment: @Thomas See the resolution, that is soooo ugly, but that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the SMB2 Redirector Cache of Windows:

We need to disable the annoying cache temporarily by doing:

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
    Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"cd '$pwd'; & '$PSCommandPath';`"";
    exit;
}

$c = Get-SmbClientConfiguration
$dc=$c.DirectoryCacheLifetime
$fc=$c.FileInfoCacheLifetime
$fnc=$c.FileNotFoundCacheLifetime
Set-SmbClientConfiguration -Force -DirectoryCacheLifetime 0 -FileInfoCacheLifetime 0 -FileNotFoundCacheLifetime 0

// Normal kopieren hier !!!!

Set-SmbClientConfiguration -Force -DirectoryCacheLifetime $dc -FileInfoCacheLifetime $fc -FileNotFoundCacheLifetime $fnc
```

This is a pain in the ass, but solves the issues.